# Add all item from ObservableCollection to field another ObservableCollection(Different class)

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have two ObversableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<SearchIDResult> _Found;
public ObservableCollection<Clip> _clipsFound;
```

Classes Clip and SearchIDResult

```
public class SearchIDResult
{
    Clip Clip;
    string Property;

    SearchIDResult(Clip AddedClip) 
    {
        Clip = AddedClip;
    }
}

public class Clip
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add all items from `_clipsFound` collection to `_Found` collection to field `Clip` of class `SearchIDResult`.

Something like this:

```
foreach (Clip clip in _clipsFound)
{
    SearchIDResult var = new SearchIDResult(clip);
    _Found.Add(var);
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Edit my discription. Please, look at them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forget the `new` keyword, try this please:

```
SearchIDResult var = new SearchIDResult(clip);
_Found.Add(var);
```

Also... `var` is a C# language keyword, although apparantly legal to use as a variable name, in general I would not recommend doing so.

Alternative (replaces both lines):

```
_Found.Add(new SearchIDResult(clip));
```

Answer (score 0):

I just need public constructor. Trouble was been here

```
 public class SearchIDResult
        {
            Clip Clip;
            string Property;
            public SearchIDResult(Clip AddedClip) 
            {
                Clip = AddedClip;
            }
        }
```